# How do I check two conditions at the same time in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop, enumerate

I have a list of words in their labels '0' or '1'.
I want to access and count how many words in my list are ending in -a whose label is 1 and how many words ending in -o whose label is 0. My idea was to access the first and second element of the list using enumerate as below, but that does not work. How could I do this?

```
ts=['0','carro','1', 'casa', '0', 'mapa','1','fantasma']

obj1 = enumerate(ts)

    for j, element in obj1:
        if j=='0' and element[-1]=='o':
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have a mixed list where the odd elements are the labels, and the pair elements are words. You want to operate some code (count and more) when you meet either of the two conditions:

1. label = "0", word ends with "o"
2. label = "1", word ends with "a"

Following @[Olvin Roght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10824407/olvin-roght) suggestion (who commented under your question):

```py
for j, element in zip(ts[0::2], ts[1::2]):
    if (j == "0" and element[-1] == "o") or (j == "1" and element[-1] == "a"):
        # your code here
```

Comment: zip(ts[0::2], ts[1::2]) is costly extra O(N) iterations , inefficent

Comment: @csguy, is it really?

Comment: @OlvinRoght `zip(ts[0::2], ts[1::2])` mean you are iterating twice on the input array to create ts[0::2] and ts[1::2]

Comment: @csguy, yes, but zip returns generator, so it's not as "inefficient" as you think ;)

Comment: @OlvinRoght yes indeed but  these are slicing operations which returns immediatly `ts[0::2] and ts[1::2]` wouldnt it first slice and then return a iterator

Comment: @csguy, yes, it will, but it still not as inefficient as you think, you can make few benchmarks and compare.

Comment: @OlvinRoght its still not a good practice, you allocate new memory for things that you dont need, O(N) extra space where as my algo is O(1)

Comment: @csguy, you can use `itertools.islice()` which returns generators as well if memory allocation is so critical for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try something like this? There's no point of using enumerate if you don't have to; just try a simple for loop.

```
ts=['0','carro','1', 'casa', '0', 'mapa','1','fantasma']

oand0count = 0
aand1count = 0

# Iterates from 1, 3, 5, etc.
for i in range(1, len(ts), 2):
    # Checks specified conditions
    if ts[i-1]=='0' and ts[i][-1]=='o':    
        oand0count += 1
    elif ts[i-1]=="1" and ts[i][-1]=="a":
        aand1count += 1
        
print(oand0count, aand1count) # Prints (1, 2)
```

Comment: Nice idea to minus 1 from index to avoid error in case if length of list is odd. +1

Answer (score 2):

You can pass generator to `sum()` function to calculate number of both conditions:

```py
first = sum(a == '0' and b == 'o' for a, (*_, b) in zip(ts[::2], ts[1::2]))
second = sum(a == '1' and b == 'a' for a, (*_, b) in zip(ts[::2], ts[1::2]))
```

---

If you do really care about memory consumption caused by slicing list twice, you can use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```py
from itertools import islice

first = sum(a == '0' and b == 'o' for a, (*_, b) in 
    zip(islice(ts, 0, None, 2), islice(ts, 1, None, 2)))
second = sum(a == '1' and b == 'a' for a, (*_, b) in 
    zip(islice(ts, 0, None, 2), islice(ts, 1, None, 2)))
```

Or you can iterate over list using indexes *(will throw an exception if list contains odd amount of elements)*:

```py
first = sum(ts[i] == '0' and ts[i + 1][-1] == 'o' for i in range(0, len(ts), 2))
second = sum(ts[i] == '1' and ts[i + 1][-1] == 'a' for i in range(0, len(ts), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Time:O(N)
Space: O(1)
Solution

if length of the list is guranteed to be even numbers, u can

```
for i in range(0, len(ts), 2):
    if ts[i] =='0' and ts[i + 1].endswith('o'):
        # do whatever u want
```

You need to check what enumerate does. Its not what you think it does. I can tell this by looking at your code

Comment: Forgot the other condition: `ts[i] == '1' and ts[i + 1].endswith('a')`